# What is the proper way to draw my 3D objects with shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have an OBJ & MTL file exported from 3DS Max that is a complete chess set. In my end result, I would like to be able to select a game piece & then select a square to move it too. The  elements I am having problems tying together are:

- Object selection
- Shaders

I have my object importer working in two ways.

1) Group everything together with like materials into a struct called `Mesh` and loop through all the `model.meshes` drawing each frame.

2) Identify the board, each square, & each game piece and place the relevant vertices, material, etc into a struct called `GroupObject`. They are placed in `model.objects` which I loop through drawing each frame.

Here is a screenshot of what each option described in #1 and #2 look like. In the top 1/2 of the SS, I just draw out the meshes and all the shading looks right, but nothing is selectable. In the bottom 1/2, I can select a game piece or a square just fine, but the model looks like crap.

http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/2158/chesst.png

Additionally, if I use the shader with the code from #2, panning & zooming slows down to a crawl. It is almost completely unresponsive.

Here is the method called to draw the objects every frame. The first 2 commented lines is where I try option 1, and just draw my struct `Mesh`'s and it looks good. Rotating & Zooming are smooth as well, but I cannot select an object b/c I can't do the glPushName of a `Mesh`. Right now, the code is setup looping through each `model.objects` so I can run the `glPushName( (int)object );` which is necessary for the picking/selection of a game piece or square. The commented out section is where I try and apply the shader that is very slow when looping through `model.objects` (no slow down when looping `model.mesh`'s )

```
 glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//for (int i = 0; i < model.getNumberOfMeshes(); ++i)
//{
for ( int i = 0; i < (int)model.objects.size(); i++ )
{
    ModelOBJ::GroupObject *object = model.objects[i];

    glPushName( (int)object );

    int faceSize = (int)object->faces.size();

    for ( int j = 0; j < faceSize; j++ )
    {

        ModelOBJ::Face *face = object->faces[j];
        pMaterial = &model.getMaterial( face->materialId );


        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, (GLfloat *)pMaterial->ambient);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, (GLfloat *)pMaterial->diffuse);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, (GLfloat *)pMaterial->specular);
        glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, pMaterial->shininess * 128.0f);

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        drawFace( *face );

        //if (pMaterial->bumpMapFilename.empty())
        //{
            // Per fragment Blinn-Phong code path.

        //  glUseProgram(blinnPhongShader);

        //  // Bind the color map texture.

        //  texture = nullTexture;

        //  if (enableTextures)
        //  {
        //      iter = modelTextures.find(pMaterial->colorMapFilename);

        //      if (iter != modelTextures.end())
        //          texture = iter->second;
        //  }

        //  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        //  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        //  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        //  // Update shader parameters.

        //  glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(
        //      blinnPhongShader, "colorMap"), 0);
        //  glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(
        //      blinnPhongShader, "materialAlpha"), pMaterial->alpha);
        //}        
    }
    glPopName();
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glUseProgram(0);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

Here is the drawFace method in case it's relevant

```
void GLEngine::drawFace(ModelOBJ::Face &face)
{
if ( (int)face.numVertices <= 3 )
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
else 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

for ( int v = 0; v < (int)face.numVertices; v++ )
{
    if ( (int)face.numUVWs > v && face.UVWs != NULL )
        glTexCoord2f(face.UVWs[v]->x, face.UVWs[v]->y);

    if ( (int)face.numNormals > v && face.normals != NULL )
        glTexCoord3d(face.normals[v]->x, face.normals[v]->y, face.normals[v]->z);

    if ( (int)face.numVertices > v && face.vertices != NULL )
        glVertex3f(face.vertices[v]->x, face.vertices[v]->y, face.vertices[v]->z);
}
glEnd();
}
```

And here is the shader I am using

```
Per-fragment Blinn-Phong shader for a single directional light source.

[vert]


varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{
    normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;    
}

[frag]


uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform float materialAlpha;

varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{   
    vec3 n = normalize(normal);

    float nDotL = max(0.0, dot(n, gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz));
    float nDotH = max(0.0, dot(normal, vec3(gl_LightSource[0].halfVector)));
    float power = (nDotL == 0.0) ? 0.0 : pow(nDotH, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);

    vec4 ambient = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].ambient;
    vec4 diffuse = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].diffuse * nDotL;
    vec4 specular = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].specular * power;
    vec4 color = gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor + ambient + diffuse + specular;

    gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(colorMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    gl_FragColor.a = materialAlpha;
}
```

How would you merge all of these functions together? My first thought is to draw all the `model.objects` with none of the material information and make them transparent. Then run through a second loop and draw all the `model.meshes` complete with material & using the shader. But then I thought when I start moving game pieces to a new square, how will I make sure the proper shading is applied to the piece's new position. When I select the transparent `GroupObject` and it translate's to a new square, will the piece still have the proper shading?

What is the best way to fix the problem I am having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you send your normal as a texture coordinate in `GLEngine::drawFace`:

```
glTexCoord3d(face.normals[v]->x, face.normals[v]->y, face.normals[v]->z);
```

You shader expect it to be as a `glNormal3d`, as you can see here:

```
normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
```

Comment: Hmm. That seems to be a mistake. I will change that tonight and see what happens

Comment: Also, do you think that has to do with why everything slows to a crawl when using the shader with drawFace?

Comment: I believe when I exported from 3ds max I forced them to be triangles, so I will try the glBegin & glEnd outside the face.size() loop. I will report back tonight. Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: My chess pieces look much better! The squares on the board are all white, but I imagine that's some lighting problem. The performance is better, but choppy still. I may try doing it using the stencil buffer for picking and drawing all vertices with like materials together for performance. http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7186/chess2f.png